# Spring shell with command line runner interface

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, command-line-arguments, spring-shell

I have a problem while running spring boot spring shell application. I have implemented commandlinerunner but its never called during application startup.

```
@Component
public class ParamReader implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        if(args.length>0) {
            System.out.println(Arrays.asList(args).stream().collect(Collectors.joining(", ")));
        }
    }
}
```

when i run exit command from shell, its calling the run method and then program terminates. I tried implementing commandlinerunner on Spring application main class but the result is same.

Answer (score 1):

Spring shell uses an `ApplicationRunner` with `@Order` annotation and `precedence 0`.
You could try the following:

```java
@Order(-1)
@Component
public class ParamReader implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        if(args.length>0) {
            System.out.println(Arrays.asList(args).stream().collect(Collectors.joining(", ")));
        }
    }
}
```